# Where and how to do network call when using fragments

Tags: android, http, networking, fragment

I am building an app that has fragments. Im not entirely sure when to make a http nw call to get data to populate components within these fragments. I have a call that gets all the data i need for all my fragments to draw the screen. I have tested that a async task gets that data ok but in the postExecute i don't have access to components unless im in the fragment class, even then how would i put it in there.

I can do a asyncTask and see my data coming back but where do i put this, i want to make the call once.
`ActivityTileData.getLoginTileDataArray(getActivity());` currently returns dummy data, ideally this would do the network call.

```
public class StaggeredGridActivityFragment extends FragmentActivity {

private static final String TAG = "StaggeredGridActivityFragment";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); //remove title bar

    final FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

    // Create the list fragment and add it as our sole content.
    if (fm.findFragmentById(android.R.id.content) == null) {
        final StaggeredGridFragment fragment = new StaggeredGridFragment();
        fm.beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, fragment).commit();
    }
}


private class StaggeredGridFragment extends Fragment implements
        AbsListView.OnScrollListener, AbsListView.OnItemClickListener {
            private StaggeredGridView mGridView;
            private boolean mHasRequestedMore;
            private TilesAdapter mAdapter;

            private ArrayList<String> mData;

            @Override
            public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setRetainInstance(true);
            }

            @Override
            public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_sgv, container, false);
            }

            @Override
            public void onActivityCreated(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {


                //Encapsulate all within a post cereate from a async task or call a blocking http call
                super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

                mGridView = (StaggeredGridView) getView().findViewById(R.id.grid_view);

                if (savedInstanceState == null) {
                    final LayoutInflater layoutInflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
                    View header = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_header_footer, null);
                    mGridView.addHeaderView(header);
                }

                if (mAdapter == null) {
                    mAdapter = new TilesAdapter(getActivity(), R.id.summary1_value);
                }

                if (mData == null) {
                    mData = ActivityTileData.getLoginTileDataArray(getActivity());
                }


                for (String data : mData) {
                    mAdapter.add(data); //Add each mData TileAdapter element to an mAdapter where it will be further broken down and used by the TileAdapter
                }

                mGridView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                mGridView.setOnScrollListener(this);
                mGridView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
            }
```

Comment: Simply call your AsyncTask in your Activity, and have setters in your fragments to do something like `myFragment.setData(/*Whatever data*/);` when you receive your data back from the AsyncTask

Comment: Yes i have those setters built in already, basically i have everything except the http call. Really, where in the activity, code in question is my activity

Comment: Well as you said, your activity holds all your fragments, and knows if they're created, and what data each of them expects. So yeah, each of your fragment should be able to draw an empty view, and an "updated view" when called with data

Comment: See my edited comment above

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to do n/w call in onCreate of your activity and make sets of data for your each fragment and put them in arguments of fragment. You can load the data in newInstance of fragment by getting required data from bundle.I have done one project of this type and it worked for me.

Note: The above method works if the data doesn't need to change once it has been set.

Answer (score 0):

Do not make the async call inside your fragments and/or activities. If you do, you will get many issues handling config changes (like when the user rotates the screen). For my experience, what I usually do is to create a class called Loader (not the Android framework Loader class, it is an overkill for this purpose) and place your AsyncTask or loader thread there. From your fragment/activity get a reference to that class that should be implemented as a singleton (override your Application class for this) on its `onCreate()`. Then, call `loader.loadDate()` whenever you need it. If you want to handle config changes, create an observable pattern in your Loader class, so fragments and activities can register to hear loading events such as `loadFinished(data)` or `loadError(error)`. Also, if you dont want to query for data everytime a config change happens, set a catched variable inside your loader that holds the previous loaded data.

Comment: thx for the reply, appreciated but I dont understand half of that. e.g. Then, call loader.loadDate() whenever you need it. why would i call loaddate?

I can post my adapter call if you like.

Comment: The fragment will draw before the http call is completed on other thread

Comment: You call loader.loadData() because if the user rotates the screen and your fragment gets destroyed, you need to requery the data again.

Comment: Also if the user starts the activity, and it goes into the background, when the asynctask finishes, there wont be any activity to listen as it might be kill by Android. When the user comes back to the application, there wont be anything loaded in your fragments.

Comment: Ok so lets strip it back to how to ensure that the async task updates the fragments when the call comes back. I create a loader class, put my async method in that - what do i put in my postexectute method of async class?

Comment: register your activities/fragments on the loader. On the postExecute notify your registered fragments/activities. It s a simple observer pattern implementation.

Comment: Ok how do i register activities/fragmentson the loader - pass context?

Comment: and...will this not mean i have to call it from every fragment? I want to get it before any fragments are created, craete the fragments based on what i get back from http call

Comment: Register during onResume() and unregister during onPause(). Just do loader.registerListener(this). Your activity/fragment must implement an interface designed by you. When the postExecute() notifies listeners, inside the listener.notify() method place your UI update and populate your views.

Comment: No sorry, im lost.  I cant seem to call 'registerListener()' on my ActivityTileData.getLoginTileDataArray(getActivity()); which is the class that gives me back my data.